# PHP SOAP Request Issues

Tags: php, soap

I'm having issues creating a SOAP request in PHP to connect to Campaigner (email marketing tool) and upload a contact but I can use some help. The API I'm using keeps responding back with a Null object. Here is the XML I'm working off of (Works when I use SoapUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:ImmediateUpload>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ns:authentication>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns:Username>username</ns:Username>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns:Password>password</ns:Password>
     </ns:authentication>
     <ns:UpdateExistingContacts>true</ns:UpdateExistingContacts>
     <ns:TriggerWorkflow>false</ns:TriggerWorkflow>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ns:contacts>
        <ns:ContactData>
           <ns:ContactKey>
              <ns:ContactId>0</ns:ContactId>
              <ns:ContactUniqueIdentifier>test@testemail.com</ns:ContactUniqueIdentifier>
           </ns:ContactKey>
           <ns:EmailAddress>test@testemail.com</ns:EmailAddress>
           <ns:FirstName>Steve</ns:FirstName>
           <ns:LastName>Rogers</ns:LastName>
           <ns:Status>Subscribed</ns:Status>
           <ns:MailFormat>Both</ns:MailFormat>
           <ns:IsTestContact>0</ns:IsTestContact>
        </ns:ContactData>
     </ns:contacts>
  </ns:ImmediateUpload>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$wsdl = "https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01/contactmanagement.asmx?wsdl";

$trace = true;
$exceptions = true;

$Username = "username";
$Password = "password";
$UpdateExistingContacts = true;
$TriggerWorkflow = false;
$ContactId = 0;
$ContactUniqueIdentifier= "test@testemail.com";
$EmailAddress = "test@testemail.com";
$FirstName = "Steve";
$LastName = "Rogers";
$Status = "Subscribed";
$MailFormat = "Both";
$IsTestContact = 0;


$params = array (
 "Username" => $Username,
 "Password" => $Password,
"UpdateExistingContacts" => $UpdateExistingContacts,
"TriggerWorkflow" => $TriggerWorkflow,
"ContactId" => $ContactId,
"ContactUniqueIdentifier" => $ContactUniqueIdentifier,
"EmailAddress" => $EmailAddress,
"FirstName" => $FirstName,
"LastName" => $LastName,
"Status" => $Status,
"MailFormat" => $MailFormat,
"IsTestContact" => $IsTestContact
);

try{
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
$response = $client->__call("ImmediateUpload", array($params));
} catch (Exception $e){
echo "error";
echo $e ->getMessage();
echo 'Last Response: '.$client->__getLastResponse();
}

var_dump($response);
?>
```

Here is the response I get back:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (0) {}
```

It's definitely a formatting issue on my part because I get a successful response with SoapUI that writes to Campaigner and I only get this error when trying to do it through PHP. I appreciate any help you can offer!

Thank you,
Logan

Update:
I was able to figure out that it is the way I'm structuring the request... Here is the actual response back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Header><ResponseHeader xmlns="https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01">
<ErrorFlag>true</ErrorFlag>
<ReturnCode>U_4.5.1.3_USERNAME-AND-PASSWORD-REQUIRED</ReturnCode>
<ReturnMessage>Username and Password is required.</ReturnMessage>
</ResponseHeader>
</soap:Header><soap:Body><ImmediateUploadResponse xmlns="https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01" />
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Troubleshooting the SOAP call**

You are already ahead of the game by using SoapUI to create a known working request.  Good work.
You suspect the format of the request is not correct in PHP.  To verify that, inspect the raw SOAP XML with `var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());` and see what you get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:ns1="https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:ImmediateUpload>
        <ns1:UpdateExistingContacts>true</ns1:UpdateExistingContacts>
        <ns1:TriggerWorkflow>false</ns1:TriggerWorkflow>
    </ns1:ImmediateUpload>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Definitely does not look like your SoapUI request.  So why is this happening?  Let's take a look at the output of `var_dump($client->__getFunctions());` and look for ImmediateUpload:

```
array(32) {
  [0]=>
  string(68) "ImmediateUploadResponse ImmediateUpload(ImmediateUpload $parameters)"
```

So we see here that the method ImmediateUpload() takes one variable $parameters of type ImmediateUpload.

But what does the structure of the ImmediateUpload look like?  Let's take a look at the output of `var_dump($client->__getTypes());` and look for that type:

```
array(88) {
  [0]=>
  string(212) "struct ImmediateUpload {
 Authentication authentication;
 boolean UpdateExistingContacts;
 boolean TriggerWorkflow;
 ArrayOfContactData contacts;
 ArrayOfInt globalAddToGroup;
 ArrayOfInt globalRemoveFromGroup;
}"
```

ImmediateUpload is a structure with six fields: 1 Authentication, 2 booleans, and 3 arrays.  So the $parameters object we pass in must follow this structure.  We can further inspect `__getTypes()` to look for the rest of the data types:

```
[1]=>
  string(61) "struct Authentication {
 string Username;
 string Password;
}"
  [2]=>
  string(55) "struct ArrayOfContactData {
 ContactData ContactData;
}"
  [3]=>
  string(357) "struct ContactData {
 ContactKey ContactKey;
 NullableElement EmailAddress;
 NullableElement FirstName;
 NullableElement LastName;
 NullableElement PhoneNumber;
 NullableElement Fax;
 ContactStatus Status;
 ContactMailFormat MailFormat;
 boolean IsTestContact;
 ArrayOfCustomAttribute CustomAttributes;
 ArrayOfInt AddToGroup;
 ArrayOfInt RemoveFromGroup;
}"
```

**Fixing the code**

Now we will fix the code.
let's construct a data structure that looks like ImmediateUpload.  To keep it simple I will use arrays instead of classes (either way will work in PHP).  Let's start by creating a contact:

```
$contact1 = array(
  "ContactKey"        => array("ContactId" => $ContactId, "ContactUniqueIdentifier" => $ContactUniqueIdentifier),
  "EmailAddress"      => $EmailAddress,
  "FirstName"         => $FirstName,
  "LastName"          => $LastName,
  "PhoneNumber"       => array('', true),
  "Fax"               => array('', true),
  "Status"            => $Status,
  "MailFormat"        => $MailFormat,
  "IsTestContact"     => $IsTestContact,
  "CustomAttributes"  => array(),
  "AddToGroup"        => array(),
  "RemoveFromGroup"   => array(),
);
```

And now we'll construct the ImmediateUpload parameter:

```
$params = array (
  'authentication'          => array("Username" => $Username, "Password" => $Password),
  "UpdateExistingContacts"  => $UpdateExistingContacts,
  "TriggerWorkflow"         => $TriggerWorkflow,
  "contacts"                => array($contact1),
  "globalAddToGroup"        => array(),
  "globalRemoveFromGroup"   => array(),
);
```

Run your code again.  Now inspect the XML of the request after making the call, and it should look very similar to your SoapUI request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:ImmediateUpload>
        <ns1:authentication>
            <ns1:Username>username</ns1:Username>
            <ns1:Password>password</ns1:Password>
        </ns1:authentication>
        <ns1:UpdateExistingContacts>true</ns1:UpdateExistingContacts>
        <ns1:TriggerWorkflow>false</ns1:TriggerWorkflow>
        <ns1:contacts>
            <ns1:ContactData>
                <ns1:ContactKey>
                    <ns1:ContactId>0</ns1:ContactId>
                    <ns1:ContactUniqueIdentifier>test@testemail.com</ns1:ContactUniqueIdentifier>
                </ns1:ContactKey>
                <ns1:EmailAddress>test@testemail.com</ns1:EmailAddress>
                <ns1:FirstName>Steve</ns1:FirstName>
                <ns1:LastName>Rogers</ns1:LastName>
                <ns1:PhoneNumber/>
                <ns1:Fax/>
                <ns1:Status>Subscribed</ns1:Status>
                <ns1:MailFormat>Both</ns1:MailFormat>
                <ns1:IsTestContact>false</ns1:IsTestContact>
                <ns1:CustomAttributes/>
                <ns1:AddToGroup/>
                <ns1:RemoveFromGroup/>
            </ns1:ContactData>
        </ns1:contacts>
        <ns1:globalAddToGroup/>
        <ns1:globalRemoveFromGroup/>
    </ns1:ImmediateUpload>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

You will still get the authentication error, but now you are one step closer to getting the call working.